# Race condition between piped command execution in a shell implementation

Tags: c, bash, exec, wait, race-condition

(I'm not sure if I chose the right wording in the heading so correct me if it sounds wrong, same about tags)

I'm writing a shell implementation which must be able to carry out piped commands. Here's a simplified piece of code which executes `ls | wc -l` (`wc` can be replaced with `sleep` or `date`):

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pid_t   family[2];
int     pipefd[2];
extern char **environ;

void    ft_exec(int i)
{
    char **ls = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    ls[0] = "/bin/ls";
    ls[1] = NULL;

    char **wc = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
    wc[0] = "/usr/bin/wc";
    wc[1] = "-l";
    wc[2] = NULL;

    printf("ENTERED BY %d\n", getpid());
    if (i == 0)
    {
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execve(ls[0], ls, environ);
    }
    if (i == 1)
    {
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execve(wc[0], wc, environ);
    }
}

void    ft_block_main_process(void)
{
    int     i;
    pid_t   terminated;
    int     status;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 2)
    {
        terminated = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        printf("%d TERMINATED; WEXITSTATUS:%d, WTERMSIG:%d, STATUS:%d\n", terminated, WEXITSTATUS(status), WTERMSIG(status), status);
        if (terminated == family[0])
            close(pipefd[1]);
        else if (terminated == family[1])
            close(pipefd[0]);
        i++;
    }
}

void    ft_interpret(void)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 2)
    {
        family[i] = fork();
        if (family[i] == 0)
            ft_exec(i);
        i++;
    }
    ft_block_main_process();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    pipe(pipefd);
    ft_interpret();
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
ENTERED BY 1511
ENTERED BY 1512
1511 TERMINATED; WEXITSTATUS:0, WTERMSIG:0, STATUS:0
       3
1512 TERMINATED; WEXITSTATUS:0, WTERMSIG:0, STATUS:0
```

which is correct.

However, if I try changing the second command to, say, `printenv`, it blows up:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pid_t   family[2];
int     pipefd[2];
extern char **environ;

void    ft_exec(int i)
{
    char **ls = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    ls[0] = "/bin/ls";
    ls[1] = NULL;

    char **printenv = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    printenv[0] = "/usr/bin/printenv";
    printenv[1] = NULL;

    printf("ENTERED BY %d\n", getpid());
    if (i == 0)
    {
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execve(ls[0], ls, environ);
    }
    if (i == 1)
    {
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execve(printenv[0], printenv, environ);
    }
}

void    ft_block_main_process(void)
{
    int     i;
    pid_t   terminated;
    int     status;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 2)
    {
        terminated = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        printf("%d TERMINATED; WEXITSTATUS:%d, WTERMSIG:%d, STATUS:%d\n", terminated, WEXITSTATUS(status), WTERMSIG(status), status);
        if (terminated == family[0])
            close(pipefd[1]);
        else if (terminated == family[1])
            close(pipefd[0]);
        i++;
    }
}

void    ft_interpret(void)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 2)
    {
        family[i] = fork();
        if (family[i] == 0)
            ft_exec(i);
        i++;
    }
    ft_block_main_process();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    pipe(pipefd);
    ft_interpret();
}
```

The output is:

```
ENTERED BY 1937
ENTERED BY 1938
TMPDIR=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n000ccj800334_/T/
<...> // environ stuff
_=/Users/aisraely/testing/./a.out
1938 TERMINATED; WEXITSTATUS:0, WTERMSIG:0, STATUS:0
1937 TERMINATED; WEXITSTATUS:0, WTERMSIG:13, STATUS:13
```

Now if the same is run in `bash`, it exits with 0:

```
bash-3.2$ ls | printenv
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
<...> // environ stuff
_=/usr/bin/printenv
bash-3.2$ echo $?
0
```

I do realize that, according to the manpage of `pipe()`, writing on a widowed pipe forces the writing process to terminate by receiving a SIGPIPE (whose value is properly extracted by the `WTERMSIG()` macro), and that `printenv` exits earlier, `ls` tries to write to it but sees no reader and catches SIGPIPE. But why in some cases this is not true? Why my executing program doesn't exit with a 0 when it should? Is it because of `ls`?

Comment: Since printenv does not expect any input, it might quit before ls has finished. Or the other way around.

Comment: I tried with `date` and `sleep`, which also don't seem to be waiting for an input, but it still either succeeds or fails because of SIGPIPE

Comment: You might want to wait for the first process to quit before you close the reading end of the pipe (given that the second process has quit before).

Comment: i'm sorry, but this not an option -- `cat /dev/urandom | head -c 100` will fall into a deadlock then

Comment: Then you have to kill the first process before, what do you expect? You already know the reason for the misbehavior: You are closing the pipe too soon. Think about the correct timing, and react accordingly. There is no magic silver bullet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is normal behavior. The exit status of the shell pipeline is usually the exit status of the rightmost command on the pipeline.

The GNU Bash shell has a `pipefail` option that can be enabled. When enabled, the exit status of the pipeline is the exit status of the rightmost command that exited with a non-zero exit status.

For example:

```shell
bash$ set -o pipefail  # turn pipefail option on
bash$ seq 0 1000000 | date
Thu Aug 26 14:49:51 UTC 2021
bash$ echo $?
141
bash$ set +o pipefail  # turn pipefail option off
bash$ seq 0 1000000 | date
Thu Aug 26 14:50:10 UTC 2021
bash$ echo $?
0
bash$
```

The exit status `141` is due to the `seq` command being terminated by a `SIGPIPE` signal.